# One language for Smart TV,Android TV and Fire TV

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv, android-tv, smart-tv, amazon-fire-tv

Can we use one language to build Smart TV,android TV and Fire TV.
If yes.please guide me or give me some reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use one programming language to develop for multiple TV platforms, the best approach would be to build it using web technology. A good starting point is the [TV Application Layer](http://fmtvp.github.io/tal/getting-started/introducing-tal.html) library created by the BBC. On Amazon Fire TV and Android TV, run this inside a WebView in an Android app.

Comment: Straight Android Java will cover both Android TV and Fire TV. You do not have to use a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

1) Fire TV  Android-based Fire OS  called "Mojito," version 3.0 which is compatible with Android Lollipop version number 5.1.0.

2) Android Tv again runs android

3) Samsung SmartTv is running Tizen OS wich is different type of os than android.

There for you can run the same app on fire tv and android tv written by googles android tv SDK

but not on SmartTv . For this you need Tizen SDK